# EM Fields Transmitted from an antenna and photons

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

What is the relationship between The EM waves (light) and photons in some context i studied light as photons and others as EM fields but how they are related....another questions : what's the name of the field of study that allows me to study antenna and wave propagation on the particle level (photons) and the relationship between different kind of particles in the matter

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called Quantum Electrodynamics, but I am not very knowledgeable in it to answer the first question properly.

Comment: ...this has *got* to be a duplicate, I just can't find of what...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we interpret polarization and frequency when we are dealing with one single photon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78933/). The question linked is not a *precise* duplicate, but the answer talks about the correspondence between photon states and EM waves, which is asked here.

Comment: in what academic discipline can i study Quantum electrodynamics in details including all physics and mathematics needed ??

Comment: That's a question that is too broad, and shows too little research effort (try google & wikipedia first...).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90646/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47105/2451 and links therein.